# Not able use tooltip for multiple elements with same event in React from react-portal-tooltip

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I'm trying to utilize tooltip for multiple elements data is not updating with respect to the element, I can see the message from last element for all the elements. Kindly suggest me some solution for multiple tooltips.

```
<div id="hoverMe" onMouseEnter={this.showTooltip} onMouseLeave ={this.hideTooltip}>
    Hover me!!!
</div>         

<div id="leaveme" onMouseEnter={this.showTooltip} onMouseLeave={this.hideTooltip}>
    Hover mine!!!
</div>
```

here is render function

```
import ToolTip from 'react-portal-tooltip';

showTooltip(e) {
    console.log(e, e.target, e.target.name, e.options);
    this.setState({isTooltipActive: true})
}
hideTooltip(e) {
   this.setState({isTooltipActive: false})
}

 this.showTooltip = this.showTooltip.bind(this);
 this.hideTooltip = this.hideTooltip.bind(this);

this.state = {
  isTooltipActive : false
}
```

And one more method which I had tried is that passing message as a parameter as follows

```
toolTip(e, value) {
    console.log(e, value);
    // this.setState({isTooltipActive: true});
    return (<ToolTip active={this.state.isTooltipActive} position="top" 
      arrow="center" parent="#hoverMe">
        <div>
            <p>{value}</p>
        </div>
    </ToolTip>);
  }

 <div id="hoverMe" onMouseEnter={(e) => this.toolTip(e, "hrloo mcsdo!!1")} 
      onMouseLeave={this.hideTooltip}>
    Hover me!!!
 </div>
```

But, unfortunately It's not working hope It have some mistakes. Suggest me some workable way in to thisenter code here

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ToolTip from 'react-portal-tooltip';

class AddAlertForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.setAlertDetails(props);

    this.showTooltip = this.showTooltip.bind(this);
    this.hideTooltip = this.hideTooltip.bind(this);
    this.toolTip = this.toolTip.bind(this);
  }

  setAlertDetails(props) {
    const applicationApiNames = [];
    const appNameOptions = [];
    const appListForUser = [];

    this.state = {
      isTooltipActive : false
    };
  }

  showTooltip(e) {
    console.log(e, e.target, e.target.name, e.options);
    this.setState({isTooltipActive: true})
  }
  hideTooltip(e) {
    this.setState({isTooltipActive: false})
  }

  toolTip(e, value) {
    console.log(e, value);
    // this.setState({isTooltipActive: true});
    return (<ToolTip active={this.state.isTooltipActive} position="top" arrow="center" parent="#hoverMe">
        <div>
            <p>{value}</p>
        </div>
    </ToolTip>);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="alert-formdiv">
        <div id="page-wrap">
          <form name="add_new_alert_form" className="form-style">

            <div id="hoverMe" onMouseEnter={(e) => this.toolTip(e, "hrloo mcsdo!!1")} onMouseLeave={this.hideTooltip}>
                Hover me!!!
            </div>

            <div id="leaveme" onMouseEnter={this.toolTip} onMouseLeave={this.hideTooltip}>
                  Hover mine!!!
            </div>

            <hr />
            <Button type="submit" label={formButtonLabel} onClick={this.handleSubmit} />
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}

AddAlertForm.propTypes = {
  userEmail: React.PropTypes.string,
  notificationId: React.PropTypes.string,
  appName: React.PropTypes.string,
  applicationApiName: React.PropTypes.string,
  applicationInstanceId: React.PropTypes.string,
  alertName: React.PropTypes.string,
  alertDescription: React.PropTypes.string,
  alertTypeSelection: React.PropTypes.string,
  alertThresholdDuration: React.PropTypes.number,
  alertThresholdCount: React.PropTypes.number,
  alertCriteriaPatternMatch: React.PropTypes.string,
  minJobCountThForFrequency: React.PropTypes.number,
  minJobCountThForFreqCount: React.PropTypes.number,
  timeRangeStart: React.PropTypes.string,
  timeRangeEnd: React.PropTypes.string,
  alertComputationInterval: React.PropTypes.number,
  notificationSuppressionDuration: React.PropTypes.number,
  alertEnable: React.PropTypes.string,
  alertDistributionList: React.PropTypes.string,
  action: React.PropTypes.string,
  isFromChart: React.PropTypes.bool,
  alertCategory: React.PropTypes.string,
  closeButtonHandler: React.PropTypes.func,
  userAction: React.PropTypes.string,
  workflowName: React.PropTypes.string,
};


export default connect(props => ({ userEmail: props.userProfile.email }))(AddAlertForm);
```

Comment: Could you show us the render function?

Comment: I will add whole code in it

Comment: Code been added on top last file contains render function and all the required code I did for it @soupette